# How to Scaffold Database tables in easy way?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a database with many tables. I want to scaffold it with my ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC project. Problem is: I do not want all the tables but only some of them.

Let's say there are 100 tables and I want to scaffold only 40 of them.

I know the command

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=;Database=;user id=;password=;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
        -OutputDir -Tables
```

but in this way, I'd have to write all the tables' name 1 by 1.

Is there an easy way that I can scaffold many tables or is there a command to scaffold the ones starting with an `'a'`?

Comment: Use the database first metho: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/workflows/database-first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [EF Core Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.EFCorePowerTools) have a UI for selecting which tables to scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify based on schema using the `--schema` option or by table using the `--table` option

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#specifying-tables

Comment: I have to write names of 50 tables again. I do not want to lose time with that.

Comment: Those are the limitations of the EF scaffold tool. You could probably write your own command line script in a scripting language of your choice to parse a file containing all the table names and add the arguments to the command.

Comment: @aoiTenshi What about the time you lose by complaining on SO?

Comment: @AustinC That's an information which I can use as a function all of my life. What a comment from a programmer...